# How to add multiply annotation in mapVIew

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mapkit, mkmapview

I have **mapView** and address from **firebase**. Now i can add in **mapView** only one annotation, but in **print("Address (self.allAddresses)")** i got three address:

**Address Москва, Пресненская набережная д.8, квартира 195, подъезд 94**

**Address Москва, ул. Правды д.24 строение 3**

**Address Москва,ул.Электрозаводская д.21**

How i can add three or more annotations?

My firebase:

```
{
  «Address» : {
    «AddressOne» : {
      "address" : "Москва, Пресненская набережная д.8, квартира 195, подъезд 94",
    },
    "AddressTwo» : {
      "address" : "Москва, ул. Правды д.24 строение 3",
    },
    "AddressThree» : {
      "address" : "Москва,ул.Электрозаводская д.21",
    }
  }
}
```

And my code:

```
class AddressesMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var allAddresses: String = ""

    var count = 0

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    var addressRef: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addressRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Address")

        loadAddressFromFirebase()

    }
    func loadAddressFromFirebase() {

        addressRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for address in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                let value = address.value as! NSDictionary

                self.allAddresses = value["address"] as? String ?? ""

                print("Address \(self.allAddresses)")

                if self.count < self.allAddresses.count {

                    let addresses = self.allAddresses

                    self.geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addresses, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in

                        print("Address - \(addresses)")

                        guard error == nil else { return }

                        guard let placemarks = placemarks else { return }

                        if let placemark = placemarks.first {

                            self.mapView.addAnnotation(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))

                        }

                        self.count += 1
                        print("Count - \(self.count)")
                    })
                }   
            }  
        }) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this line (`self.mapView.addAnnotation`) run three times?

Comment: One times. I think problem here, but i can not understand what to do with it

Comment: Does the for loop iterate 3 times?

Comment: No, I think this is due to the fact that geocoder can processing only one address, but i could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try allocating geoCoder wihtin the 'for' loop.
- Call `geocoder.cancelGeocode()` method.

  ```
          let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
          geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addresses, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in

              print("Address - \(addresses)")

              guard error == nil else { return }

              guard let placemarks = placemarks else { return }

              if let placemark = placemarks.first {

                  self.mapView.addAnnotation(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))

              }

              self.count += 1
              print("Count - \(self.count)")
              geocoder.cancelGeocode()
          })
  ```

Comment: Great, it worked, thanks a lot. And why didn't I think to try to remove a loop... ))